How can I get the orbs to stop jumping around?
Made with GeoNodes. How can I stop the orbs from jumping around? Version is Blender 3.1.

Video Link: https://youtu.be/asyiEA4VYm0
File Link: 

Sorry I could not help as I am still using Blender 3.6, but I find suspicious the "Warning" signs displayed for most of the nodes. Could you give us the message displayed when moving the mouse over ?

@StefLAncien It's the same in Blender 4.02 and 4.1 with most nodes titled 'Undefined' and displayed in red with no 'orbs' visible so I don't know where they came from or what they are supposed to do.

@StefLAncien It's just a notification. "Legacy node will be removed before Blender 4.0" Nothing that would cause an issue now.

Could you write in the question the Blender version you are using ? Point Scale node is documented for Blender up to 3.0...

@StefLAncien added it. Blender 3.1

The screenshot is taken in Blender 3.1, but those are pre Blender 3.0 nodes. It is the old system, some people like me never learned that one :D
